# Why is $Hilb_{P^n}^{1, O(1)} = P^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$Hilb_{P^n}^{1, O(1)}$ is the functor associating to a scheme $X$ the set of flat and proper over $X$ closed subschemes $Y$ in $P^n_X$ so that for all $x \in X$, the Hilbert polynomial with respect to $O(1)$ of the fiber of $Y$ over $x$ is 1. (I think this is what the notation means anyway.)

It is supposed to be represented by $P^n$.

Somehow this is the same functor as the one sending $X$ to all equivalence classes of surjections $O_X^{n+1} \to L$, where $L$ can be any invertible sheaf on $X$?

The natural first thing to do is to look at the closed subscheme exact sequence, and this gives a surjection $O_{P^n_X} \to F$ on $P^n_X$, where $F$ is flat over $X$ and has support which is proper over $X$. (Then I want to twist by $O(1)$ and push forward, but I'm not sure how to proceed at that point.)

Maybe this is completely obvious - but I don't see it.

Thanks!

(More generally, this is supposed to be about realizing grassmanians inside the Hilbert scheme.)

Comment: @Hoot It's $x + 1$ ... I'm not sure I see what the issue is.

Comment: If $Y\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ has Hilbert polynomial 1 with respect to $\mathcal{O}(1)$, then $Y$ is just a $k$-rational point. From this it is easy to see that the Hilbert scheme is just the $k$-rational points of $\mathbb{P}^n$ for any $k$ and then the Hilbert scheme is just the projective space itself.

Comment: I wonder if it's a good idea to focus on any special properties of $\mathbf P^n$ (what's your base, by the way?), since the result should be the same for any $X$ with a specified ample sheaf. Sorry again.

Comment: I take it back: I now think that this is a good exercise. Maybe this helps, although I think I see another way: if you have a point $[Z]$ on this Hilbert scheme, what relationship does the subscheme $Z \subseteq X \times \mathbf P^n$ have to the morphism $f\colon X \to \mathbf P^n$ that we're supposed to get?

Comment: @Hoot I think the connection is that the structure morphism $P^n_X \to X$ restricted to such a $Z$ (with hilbert polynomial condition amounting to restricting the fibers) is an isomorphism, hence one can get a map to $P^n$ by undoing this isomorphism and then projecting. Technically one needs Noetherianness for all of this -- I'm not sure if this is a problem when thinking about functors. I'm writing up an answer now.

Comment: Right, I want it to be the graph. Maybe one can translate this purely into pushing sheaves around but I think it's a nice picture. IIRC Grothendieck needs locally noetherian to construct these things in generality so I don't see a huge problem with assuming that. It would be nice to do better in such a degenerate case, I agree.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks that was helpful.

Comment: @Hoot Thanks for helping. I don't at all mind working with Noetherian schemes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: If $\pi : X \to Y$ is a finite map of Noetherian schemes whose degree at every point of $Y$ is $0$ or $1$, then $\pi$ is a closed embedding.

Proof: See 19.1.2 in Ravi Vakils notes.

Proposition: A surjective flat closed immersion is an isomorphism.

Proof:  ?

Reference: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05XD

Lemma: A proper flat map $Z \to X$ with fibers that are all trivial field extensions is an isomorphism.

Pf: Follows from above two propositions.

Now, comparing the functors:

Any $X$ point of $P^n$ gives (by universal property) a closed embedding of $X$ into $P^n_X$ (by the cancellation lemma and separateness of $P^n_X$ over $X$) which trivially is proper and flat over $X$ and the fibers have Hilbert polynomial $1$ (since this last thing is true for a closed $k$-point in $P^n_k$).

Conversely, suppose we are given a closed subscheme $Z$ of $P^n_X$, which is proper and flat over $X$ and which has, for each $x \in X$, $Z_x \in P^n_x$ a subscheme with hilbert polynomial one. This implies that $Z_x$ is dimension zero, and just a $spec K(x)$. So in fact $\pi|Z \to X$ is a proper, flat morphism with for all $x \in X$, the fibers over the residues fields of all points being a trivial field extension. So $\pi$ is an isomorphism. One now obtains an embedding by composing $\pi^{-1}$ with the projection $P^n_X \to P^n$.

(There is a technical detail here, depending on the interpretation of $x \in X$. I am going to assume this means over all residue fields of points in $X$.)

Moreover, this bijection is functorial.

So, this demonstrates the $Hilb^{1, O(1)}_{P^n}$ and $Hom(_,P^n)$ define the same functors when restricted to the subcategory of Noetherian schemes. I don't know if this is a sufficiently big subcategory of the category of all schemes in order to conclude that the two functors are naturally isomorphic.